# Logstash listens to its own logs

Tags: logstash

I want to be able to track logstash logs in case of an error.
I want to be able to monitor issues when logstash tries to send events to output destination. I've checked the monitor API but it doesn't fulfills my requirements.

Is it a good practice to use file input plugin  and set the path to its own log?

Comment: Something that worries me about doing this using a logstash is that if logstash logs an error that causes an exception in the logstash pipeline it could end up endlessly repeating the same message. I think it would be better to consume the logstash logs using filebeat.

Comment: Good point but on the other hand I cannot process the log with filebeat (for example use grok)